# PostgreSQL - max number of parameters length change?

Tags: postgresql

can any one please help me for how I can increase the PostgreSQL - max number of parameters length. I don't want to do any other way i want to use normal query as I am using. but if I am passing 90,000 parameters in IN Query then how I make it possible to execute this query?

Comment: Show us your current query.

Comment: 90,000 parameters in a IN() statement is going to be very very slow. Use a temp table and JOIN to this table, this can be much faster. You can fill this temp table using COPY

Comment: Never tought at arrays as IN?

Answer (score -2):

If you believe this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx the number of parameters for example in a stored proc, statement, function, ... are fix.

Comment: Postgres is not SQL Server